# ball in universal cover belongs to the union of actions on a section?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology

M is an n-dim manifold. $\pi :\tilde M \to M$ the universal cover of M. $\tilde p \in \tilde M$ a lift of p. We choose a measurable section $j:{B_1}\left( p \right) \to {B_1}\left( {\tilde p} \right)$, i.e. $\pi \left( {j\left( x \right)} \right) = x$ for any $x \in {B_1}\left( p \right)$. Let $T = j\left( {{B_1}\left( p \right)} \right)$. Let S be the union of g(T) over all $g \in {\pi _1}\left( M \right)$ such that $g\left( T \right) \cap {B_1}\left( {\tilde p} \right) \ne \emptyset $. Is then ${B_1}\left( {\tilde p} \right) \subset S$?

Comment: Yes, assuming that your manifolds are Riemannian and $\pi$ is an isometric covering map; you do not even need "measurable" assumption, it is just a set-theoretic statement.   

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are taking $M$ to be Riemannian and $\tilde{M}$ to be endowed with the induced metric?

Let $\tilde{q}\in B_1(\tilde{p})$.  We want to show that $\tilde{q}\in S$. Let $q=\pi(\tilde{q})$. There exists a covering transformation $g\in \pi_1M$ such that $\tilde{q}=gj(q)$, so we just need to prove that $q\in B_1(p)$.

Let $\tilde{\gamma}$ be a smooth path from $\tilde{p}$ to $\tilde{q}$ of length less than one. Then $\gamma=\pi\circ\tilde{\gamma}$ is a smooth path from $p$ to $q$ of the same length, because $\pi$ is a local isometry.  This finishes the proof.